# Utilizar biblioteca Jquery com AngularAMD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Estou a implementar AngularJS + RequireJs através do AngularAMD.

Quero adicionar a biblioteca Jquery mas retorna o seguinte erro quando uso o "$":

> Error: $ is not defined

Tenho o main.js configurado da seguinte forma:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/",

    // alias libraries paths
    paths: {
        'angular': 'libs/angular.min',
        'angular-route': 'libs/angular-route.min',
        'angular-ui-router': 'libs/angular-ui-router.min',
        'angularAMD': 'libs/angularAMD',
        'jquery': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',
        'jquery-migrate': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js'
    },

    // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
    shim: {
        'angular-route': [ 'angular' ],
        'angularAMD': [ 'angular' ],
        'angular-ui-router': [ 'angular' ]
    },

    // kick start application
    deps: ['app']
});
```

O que está errado?

Comment: Carregando o jquery antes do angular muda alguma coisa?

Comment: Senão, tenta copiar a biblioteca jquery para uma pasta `RAIZ_DO_PROJETO/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.js` e troca a conf para `jquery: 'jquery-1.9.0'`

Comment: @GabrielOshiro já fiz essas 2 modificações mas continua a dar o mesmo erro. Basta apenas declarar no require.config, certo?

Comment: Ah, é possível que o Require.js carregue os scripts rápido "demais", ou seja, antes do DOM ter sido carregado. Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938419/angular-requirejs-loading-in-the-wrong-order). Eles propõem o uso de domReady. Avisa se funcionar.

Comment: @GabrielOshiro mas o problema não é reconhecer elementos no DOM, nem sequer reconhece o jquery. Fiz um teste usando o setTimeout mas retornou o mesmo erro.

Comment: Filipe o que o @GabrielOshiro quer dizer que que no momento que você chama o `$(...)`, o jquery ainda não foi carregado, isto é só uma suposição

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então, eu entendi. O que eu fiz foi inserir o "$(...)" dentro de um setTimeout e retornou o mesmo erro, sendo assim não é um problema de carregamento, certo?

Comment: Como eu disse era apenas uma suposição e não afirmação, só testando, você tentou trocar `'//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',` por `'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim eu entendo que era só uma suposição e agradeço o vosso tempo. Considerei a hipótese, tanto que modifiquei o código para testar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento descobri o problema, tenho um ".js" no fim a mais, repare que os outros não possuem, não é preciso inserir o ".js" no path.

Comment: @GabrielOshiro descobri o problema, tenho um ".js" no fim a mais, repare que os outros não possuem, não é preciso inserir o ".js" no path.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tenho mais coisas, criei um "common.js" (intermediário entre o main.js onde tenho o require.config e o app.js onde tenho as configurações do angularjs) e lá dentro coloquei um define com as dependências: define(['angularAMD','jquery','jquery-migrate','angular','angular-ui-router'], function... Lembrando que estou a implementar o Requirejs com o AngularAMD: https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD

Comment: Mas o jQuery carregou agora?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, carregou o jquery sem problemas.

Comment: Você mesmo pode responder a sua pergunta :) sabia? Clica no botão responder. Se tiver mais duvidas durante a criação do projeto pode criar novas perguntas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, vou responder a pergunta :)

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação do jQuery.noConflict()
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o `jquery` no `shim` assim:

```
shim: {
    "jquery": {
      exports: "jquery"
    }
  }
```

Comment: ou exports: "$"

Answer (score 0):

utilize angular.element ao invés de $

angular.element serve como um alias para a função jQuery caso ele esteja carregado.

Caso não esteja carregado ele vai utilizar o jQlite que vem acoplado no angular.

```
$('xxx')
angular.element('xxx')
```

Você pode ler um pouco mais a repeito na documentação no link abaixo:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element